Unauthorized Error in Bot Framework: "Invalid AppId Passed on Token"
I am encountering a persistent issue while building and deploying a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework on a Windows 10 setup. The bot works locally using the Bot Emulator, but fails with the following error when deployed to Azure App Service and tested via Web Chat or MS Teams:

Error processing activity: [Errno Unauthorized. Invalid AppId passed on token: ] <AppId>


Setup Details:

Environment:

OS: Windows 10
Bot Framework: Using botbuilder Python SDK
Hosting: Azure App Service (using Docker)
App Registration: App ID and App Password are taken from Azure AD App Registration.


Code Summary:

Bot uses JwtTokenValidation.validate_auth_header for token validation.
Authorization header is extracted and validated against the MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD.
Token validation fails on the deployed bot with the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'required_endorsements'.


Logs:

Local Test (Bot Emulator): Works fine; Authorization header and App ID match.
Deployed Bot: Always returns 401 Unauthorized.




Troubleshooting Done So Far:

Verified App Registration:

Confirmed MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD in Azure AD.
Confirmed the bot channel is enabled for Web Chat and MS Teams.


Hardcoded Validation Check:

Decoded the token manually using jwt_decode and verified that the aud field matches MICROSOFT_APP_ID.
Skipped full validation temporarily but still faced issues in production.


Service URL and Channel ID:

Checked activity.service_url and activity.channel_id. Both look valid and consistent across tests.


Token Validation Flow:

Used the following validation code:
valid_token = await JwtTokenValidation.validate_auth_header(
    auth_header,
    MicrosoftAppCredentials(os.getenv("MICROSOFT_APP_ID"), os.getenv("MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD")),
    activity.service_url,
    activity.channel_id
)

It fails with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'required_endorsements'.



Environment Checks:

Ensured environment variables (MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD) are correctly set in .env.
Confirmed Docker setup passes environment variables correctly.




Questions:

Is there a specific requirement for JwtTokenValidation in production that we might be missing?
Could this issue be caused by differences between the Emulator and production environments (e.g., service_url, channel_id)?
Are there any known issues with JwtTokenValidation in the Python SDK causing the 'required_endorsements' error?
Should we avoid using JwtTokenValidation entirely and implement a custom validation logic?
Is there a better way to debug or trace token validation issues in the deployed environment?

Additional Details:
Here’s the authorization header and other critical details extracted during debugging:

Authorization Header:

Service URL:
https://webchat.botframework.com/

Channel ID:
webchat and MSTeams

App Credentials:
MicrosoftAppCredentials(os.getenv("MICROSOFT_APP_ID"), os.getenv("MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD"))



Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Can we please get a [mcve] instead of all the enumerated lists?
